# SIG 11 for G-WAN w/o much debug information

Tags: g-wan

The gwan (4.1.18) instance runs for about one day, and then crashed with this tracing information (Not suer how useful it is:( How to get meaningful tracing information?)

```
----------------
----------------
Sun, 27 Jan 2013 20:07:34 GMT: warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /home/gwan/gwan
0x00007f0018206148 in ?? ()
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    process 2860 "gwan" 0x00007f0018206148 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (process 2860):
#0  0x00007f0018206148 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000004 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007f0018941245 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007f0018206070 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f000b70ece8 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000000000002e in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Signal        : 11:Address not mapped to object
Signal src    : 1:.
errno         : 0
Thread        : 1
Code   Pointer: 0000004343c0 (module:gwan, function:??, line:0)
Access Address: 0001004647f0

Registers     : EAX=7f000ca04d40 CS=00000033 EIP=0000004343c0 EFLGS=000000010282
                EBX=7f000ca08eb0 SS=00000000 ESP=7f000ca04af0 EBP=00000001aeb0
                ECX=0000ffffffb0 DS=00000000 ESI=7f000ca04cf0 FS=00000033
                EDX=0000000000b0 ES=00000000 EDI=7f000ca04d9c CS=00000033

Module         :Function        :Line # PgrmCntr(EIP)  RetAddress  FramePtr(EBP)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to get meaningful tracing information?

Leaving the relevant per-thread crash information would surely have helped to give you some insights.

But as you have removed it by hand, I am assuming that you know what you are doing.

Note that running gwan under `/home/gwan/gwan -d` is not a good idea.

Rather use something like `/opt/gwan/gwan -d` because the contents of `/home` are not reachable from other accounts.

And if you are running during days without the parent angel process (-d mode) then it's even less a good idea.

That's not G-WAN-specific:

"[you should NEVER run Nginx in production with 'master_process off'](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/daemon_master_process_off.html)"

Comment: It's what I copied from the trace file w/o anything removed.

Comment: Then email us your /logs/gwan.log file so we can understand why so little information is available.